# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.keys$.previousCompile()Lsbt/TaskKey. Internal Server Error on request via http url

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I'm being a (newbie for play and scala) tried settingUp my Play + Scala build with sbt application. The server stated, But, when trying to hit / request via http url it throws error. I feel weird.

and once i update the scala version to 2.12, included lombok annotation processor, clearing .ivy2/cahce, it works. And again when i try to run the next day it shows the same error after the program startup. Please comment if anyone need more clarifications

Insights:

- The Scala version is 2.11.
- The sbt version is 0.13.7 Intellij
- version 2019.1 community edition

I tried with changing the scala versions.

It throws me the following error:

I couldn't figure out what goes wrong. And any lead would be helpful and much appreciated.

```
Internal Server Error, for (GET) [url] ->
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.Keys$.previousCompile()Lsbt/TaskKey;
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible version of dependencies.

Comment: Can u please elaborate the issue? may i know what dependency version u mean by? and once i hit that GET request again, It throws another error
`play.PlayException$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[OverlappingFileLockException: null]`